# How to decompose/unroll a Qiskit Arbitrary initialization

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-algorithms

I'm aware that to randomly initialize a quantum circuit with Qiskit, we can simply write qc.initialize(rand_state, q[0]...). However, when drawing the circuit, I see that the "initialize" function is treated as one big gate that takes in an input and outputs the initialized state.

[image]

Is there a way to decompose this "initialization gate" through python/Qiskit and run a circuit that is composed of the individual smaller gates that actually make up this large gate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example you can do

```
qc.decompose().draw()
```

The method `decompose` decomposes every gate in the circuit. This will do a single level. If you want to do another level of decomposition, call the method again.

```
qc.decompose().decompose().draw()
```

Comment: Works like magic, thank you @luciano